# How do we extract only specific rows which have the first column as a specified constraint(string) using OLEDB in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

I have an excel sheet Which has list of Marks obtained in 6 subjects of a particular Hall Ticket Number. [image: Excel Sheet]

I've been using the OLEDB in the C# Codebehind file for the webpage, and used a DataTable to store the records. But I'm not able to get through the problem, how do I extract only the rows whose first column matches with a particular string. I've tried using the following code :

```
        OleDbConnection ExConn = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand Comm = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter ODAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
        Comm.Connection = ExConn;

        ExConn.Open();
        DataTable ExSchema = ExConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        string Sheet = ExSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        ExConn.Close();

        ExConn.Open();
        Comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ["+Sheet+"] where [A] = '155U1A05A0'";
        ODAdapter.SelectCommand = Comm;
        ODAdapter.Fill(DTable);
        ExConn.Close();
```

Is there any way to only those conditionally true rows into the DataTable? Or at least to extract those rows from the DataTable? 
(I personally suspect the problem is with the CommandText. I did try various ways like A*, A% but couldn't resolve the issue).

Comment: Your narrative suggests you are using the wildcard in the wrong place with the wrong operator. Try `where [A] like '155U1A05A0*'`

Comment: No, I actually intended to use * as a replacement for the Row Number, which could be anything ranging from 1 to the end. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to get proper data from excel sheet to data table if you don't set any condition? I am asking coz I see there are some other data also in the sheet apart from the result data.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to get the complete excel sheet contents on the webpage, as a table in the GridView. Thanks.